# Create bootable partition from image

Tags: macos, ubuntu, bootable-media

I have a Macbook Pro with a dead CD drive. I don't have easy access to a replacement drive.

I'm trying to install Ubuntu, and I can't get the MBP to recognize a USB stick as a bootable media (I believe MBP's have issues with booting from USB in some cases).

Is it possible to take a disk image and write it to a partition on the HDD so that I can then boot from that partition and then install the OS onto a third partition?

Partition layout:

1. 150GB OS X
2. 50GB Ubuntu destination
3. 5GB Ubuntu install image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a great solution, and I still would like to hear if it's possible to put a bootable image on a HDD, but I ended up solving this on my own.

I first installed VMWare Fusion, then created a raw disk image that used the partition I wanted to install to ([this](http://8na.de/?p=124) shows how, I can't find the guide I used).

Once I had the VM running on the raw disk, I was able to install Windows and then reboot, then select the correct partition using Refind.

I suspect that Windows 7 is using BIOS mode instead of EFI mode, but for now I'm happy with it. Might have to re-image when I finally get a CD drive.